# If statement inline with addition in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

C# does not like the following. How can I rewrite it so it works?

```
Value1 = Value1 + (i.Cost == null || !Utils.IsNumeric(i.Cost)) ? 0 : i.Cost;
```

Comment: Why not? What error do you get?

Comment: Readibility_Of_Code = 0;

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
Value1 += (i.Cost == null || !Utils.IsNumeric(i.Cost)) ? 0 : i.Cost;
```

Comment: This is nice, tempted to say that's better than my answer in terms of readability.

Answer (score 5):

You have a mismatched parenthesis. The code should read as follows:

```
Value1 = Value1 + (i.Cost == null || !Utils.IsNumeric(i.Cost) ? 0 : i.Cost);
```

or possibly

```
Value1 = Value1 + ((i.Cost == null || !Utils.IsNumeric(i.Cost)) ? 0 : i.Cost);
```

I personally would refactor this code for readability but that is an argument for another day methinks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying way too hard to be clever.

```
if(i.Cost != null && Utils.IsNumeric(i.Cost)) Value1 += i.Cost;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Value1 is numeric and i.Cost also and you are trying to add i.Cost if possible since you will add i.Cost without any conversion if it's numeric.

```
Value1 += i.Cost ?? 0
```